# How do we determine which steady state a given set of initial condition approaches in a system?

Tags: dynamical-systems, steady-state

If we have an ordinary differential equation system with multiple steady states, how do we determine which steady state a given set of initial condition approaches in a system?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I assume your system is non-linear. In general, it is not easy. It is about finding the separatrix separating the different basins of attraction. It may not approach any state in particular, but be periodic or approach a limit cycle instead.